# Can a modern Windows 8 app (Store) use MS Access as a database?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is this possible to connect to a Microsoft Access database without hacking too much?

Comment: Just use a new version of Access and you should have no problem. Maybe are you asking about store apps?

Comment: It would be my last choice of database to use for anything.. dunno for store apps.